# In which circumstances ||Av|| = ||A|| ||v||?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let's suppose that we have an operator defined as
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
A: & \ell_2 & \to & \mathbb{C} \\
& (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty & \mapsto & \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nx_n
\end{array}\ , \quad\text{where } (c_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell_2\ .
$$

We could calculate the norm by using the Riesz theorem, which tells us that there should be a vector $a$ such that $Ax = \langle a,x\rangle$ and then $||A|| = ||a||$. In this case this is easy, because by inspection we can see that
$$
a = \left(c_n^*\right)_{n=1}^\infty\ ,
$$
and then we could calculate the norm as
$$
||A|| = ||a|| = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |c_n^*|^2\right)^{1/2}\ ,
$$
given that this summation converges to any finite number.

Now, in general we know that for any vector in $\ell_2$, we have that $||Ax|| \leq ||A||\,||x||$. So my question is, how could we determine all the vectors that satisfy the equality, i.e. the equation
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nx_n\right| = ||A|| \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2\right)^{1/2}\ .
$$

Comment: The Cauchy Schwarz inequality $|\langle c,x \rangle| \leq \|c\|\cdot \|x\|$ is tight if and only if $c,x$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom hello! How're you? Which book have you used for your first course in functional analysis, in particular the theory of normed and Banach spaces and the inner product spaces?

Comment: @S I'm doing well, I hope you are too. I used Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications*. Pedersen's *Analysis Now!* is also an excellent text, but a bit more terse and abstract.